# Passing multiple parameter values to crystal reports using SQL

Tags: sql, crystal-reports

I have in my report a few needed arguments like `'A','B','C'` and I would like to pass it using SQL.

How can I do that?

I tried `prm_szDiscType='C','N','P'` , `prm_szDiscType = C,N,P,` and `prm_szDiscType=''C'',''N'',''P''`

Comment: I have a problem, because passing the parameters will not be using only on my computer - so I can't do it using a command on my SQL.

I tried to do it using a range (from a to z) but that does not work. 

In case when I used a numbers passing a range from sql works.

I do it using this:
https://archive.sap.com/discussions/thread/2131933

And sa I said in case when i have parameters as number that works, but in case when i have string, that doesn't work :(

Comment: I'll try to explain what i meant once again.

My first problem based on the numbers - and I did it using this method.

Now in crystal report i have a paramater which is a string. This parameter can be a few letters like ,C' , 'N' and 'P'.  In sql I am trying to pass parameter to the crystal raport.

Now it looks:  .... /prm_szDiscMode=A /prm_szDiscType= ?????? /prm_szDateStart=%TODAY%   ....

and I am trying to pass the parameter szDiscType this few letter and I don't know how to do it. I tried to do it by range, as in case when the parameters were numbers but it does not work.

Comment: when a parameters are set as string.

Comment: Thanks for help, but that also does not work :(

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure how you pass parameters via URL.

In Crystal Reports desktop client, I created a Command Parameter with "Allow multiple values" check on.

[image: Command Parameter - Allows multiple values check on]

Then in my Command SQL, I use a where clause such as:

`where item in {?Item}`

When you check "Allows multiple values" on, Crystal will create the clause after `in`. If you select Value Type of String, the values you enter will automatically be wrapped in single quotes.

[image: value selection]

Credit to [ExpertsExchange thread on command parameters ;)](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/24260716/Using-Multiple-Values-for-a-Command-Parameter-in-Crystal-10.html)

Comment: This does not seem to work when working with a crystal report connected to an Oracle database. We've tried many variations of wrapping the parameter reference in the SQL with parenthesis and quotes but no luck. Get syntax errors as if it does not translate into proper SQL query in Oracle.